# Unable to open "Share" dialog

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to leverage the drive "Share dialog".
When opening the dialog I can see these exceptions in the JS console:

```
Uncaught Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12 3566089298-v2-doclist_share.js:454
nK.sendMessage 3566089298-v2-doclist_share.js:454
Mj 3566089298-v2-doclist_share.js:455
z.Yh 3566089298-v2-doclist_share.js:481
_createShareApplication 3566089298-v2-doclist_share.js:482
init share:53
(anonymous function) share:82
Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.
```

The dialog opens, but after ~1 minute of loading state I get the message "Sorry, sharing is unavailable at this time. Please try again later."
Any ideas?
I'm on Chrome Version 23.0.1271.64 m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few restrictions on the sharing dialog that make it very sensitive (and unfortunately very difficult to debug.) Essentially:

1. The application must be installed by the user
2. The app ID must be set when creating the dialog
3. The JS origin of the host page must match the origin of either the create or open URLs in the Drive SDK settings (protocol/host/port must match)

Check to make sure those conditions are met.