# Google Drive “Share” dialog not showing for "writer"

Tags: google-drive-api

We've incorporated Google Drive “Share” dialog into our web application which creates its own files, and it works perfectly thanks to the answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479082/unable-to-open-share-dialog?rq=1), but only for document owner.

Even though "writers" can easily share documents from Google Drive, that seems to be not possible externally, i.e. in our app.

This is the code which works for "owners" but fails for "writers":

```
        var s =  new gapi.drive.share.ShareClient(appId);
        s.setItemIds(fileId);
        s.showSettingsDialog();
```

Curiously, the error in JS console is the same as one can see when the script is launched from a wrong URL:

```
Refused to display 'https://drive.google.com/share?id=0B....' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'
```

We haven't found anything related to possibility to share docs by various user roles in the documentation, so we wonder if that's a bug or undocumented restriction. Any ideas are welcome.

*UPDATE*
The issue seems to have gone - it looks like Google have changed something their end.

Answer (score 0):

Your app should be checking the value of the `writersCanShare` attribute. If it's false, only owners can modify the file ACLs.

Comment: Jay, thank you for your answer. However the odd thing is that the sharing dialogue is not working even in the case when `writersCanShare = true`, which is the default value. It looks like in Google Drive the sharing dialogue is based on this setting, but in the external apps it assumes writers are never allowed to share.